# Auto generated WCF code has Boolean have a "Specified" additional field

Tags: c#, wcf, soap-client

Given a WSDL definition containing a simple Datetime field defined as follow:

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="endDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

Adding the Service reference using the built-in [tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2019)

The generated code has a new "Specified" field that was not defined in the WSDL

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.4084.0")]
.. removed fluff..
public partial class Foo {
    private System.DateTime endDateField;     // Normal field   
    private bool endDateFieldSpecified;       // New Unknow field
```

When the old generated code use to be like :

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
.. removed fluff..
public partial class Foo {
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private System.DateTime endDateField;
```

If the new "Specified" field is not set to true. The property is not serialised.
And the info is missing from the Soap Trace.

The issue is not related to VS version nor update.
The header of the file show the same version for both generated code:

> Version du runtime :4.0.30319.42000

Answer (score 0):

The issue cames from the configuration of the service reference.
Un-ticking the "Reuse types in the referenced assemblies" will produce this new "Specified" field.

Making working code that previously work, here you initialised properly your properties.
Turn into not working code with no error, but the value of every primitive type goes missing at serialisation in the SOAP Trace.

In order to fix that Reuse Type like in this image bellow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1N3F.png)

If you choose to not reuse type on purpuse in order to exclude some libraries from autogenerated code. Exclude only those one in the 2nd option of the picture.

Comment: The issue can easly be reproduce going to the reference.cs generated code. and ticking and unticking this thing.